# How to target a hidden div by clicking on an image tag that is within the same parent div? Vanilla JS Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I got this code.

Express-Handlebars:

```
{{#each bigProjectList}}
    <div class="bigProjIndividual">

        <img src="{{image}}" alt="">

        <div class="bigProjDesc">

            <h5>{{name}}</h5>
            <p>{{tech}}</p>
            <p>{{desc}}</p>

            {{#if web.gitHub}}
            <a href="{{web.github}}"target="_blank"> <img src="/github.png" alt="github"> </a>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if web.website}}
            <a href="{{web.website}}"target="_blank"> <img src="/website.png" alt="github"> </a>
            {{/if}}

        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

It is fetching the data from a json file I have in the directory.

I would like the class 'bigProjDesc' to be initially hidden and then shown once the user click on the `<img>` tag.

I am currently using vanilla JS / CSS / Express-Handlebars.

Comment: What have you actually tried? The functionality you have described is rather basic: here are some tips: (1) use `addEventListener`, (2) use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the `div.bigProjDesc` element. Optional: hide the element by default using inline style.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done pretty easy:

```js
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll('.bigProjIndividual > img');
const imgArray = Array.from(imgList); // or [].slice.call(imgList)
const className = 'is--visible';
    
    
 const toggle = node => () => {
  let desc = node.nextElementSibling; // or node.parentNode.querySelector('.bigProjDesc')
  if (desc) {
    desc.classList.toggle(className); // IE 10 +
  }
 }
 
 imgArray.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener('click', toggle(img));
 });
```

```css
.bigProjDesc {
 display: none;
}

.bigProjDesc.is--visible {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigProjIndividual">

        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">

        <div class="bigProjDesc">

            <h5>{{name}}</h5>
            <p>{{tech}}</p>
            <p>{{desc}}</p>

            <a href="{{web.github}}"target="_blank"> <img src="/github.png" alt="github"> </a>

            <a href="{{web.website}}"target="_blank"> <img src="/website.png" alt="github"> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Note: I changed your markup to make this example run in the browser. The code is given in ES6, but should be easy to translate into ES5*